# SSIS 2012 using ADO.net Source for MYSQL but cannot put a variable in the Query

Tags: mysql, ssis, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS and have read and attempted many of the examples posted online but have not managed to succeed and am hoping for some pointers please.

My source is ADO NET and I can connect to mySQL db, then my 'SQL command' is

```
SELECT * FROM file_logging
```

this works nicely, I have added a variable [user::file_loggingDate] which I get from an SQL control table(type datetime). I am trying to do

```
SELECT * FROM file_logging WHERE date > @[User::file_loggingDate]
```

but this returns an error that I have the wrong syntax near '[User::...

same goes if I go with Task Factory's syntax <@User::file_loggingDate>

I have tried to set the query as a String but I require the file_loggingDate to stay as DateTime

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't find an appropriate duplicate but the short answer is that you map expressions for ADO.NET providers in the Data Flow's Expression editor and not the specific component. Very backwards compared to the OLE DB Source but such is life

Comment: @billinkc, are you suggesting I create a variable and use the expression to define the String? if so how can I add the datetime into the string? It always returns a conversion error